# How do I show that this vector is a linear combination of column vectors of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given some $Ax = y$, I want to show $y$ is a linear combination of column vectors of $A$ if the equation has a solution.

I'm thinking along the lines of finding eigenvectors but this might not be necessary.

If there is a solution, should i find $det(Ax - y)$ and show that it is non-zero? How should I proceed?

Comment: You can write $Ax$ as $Ax=\sum_{i}x_icol_i$.

Comment: assue that x is a solution to the system then simply do matrix vector multiplication and equate the rows of the result to the components of Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write $Ax$ as

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12}\cdots & a_{1n} \\
    \vdots & a_{22}\cdots & a_{2n} \\
    a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
                   x_1 \\
                   x_2 \\
                   \vdots \\
                   x_n
                  \end{pmatrix}=x_1\begin{pmatrix}
                                    a_{11} \\
                                    \vdots \\
                                    a_{1m}
                                   \end{pmatrix}
+ x_2\begin{pmatrix}
                                    a_{21} \\
                                    \vdots \\
                                    a_{2m}
                                   \end{pmatrix} + \cdots + 
x_n\begin{pmatrix}
                                    a_{n1} \\
                                    \vdots \\
                                    a_{nm}
                                   \end{pmatrix}
$$

Therefore, if $Ax=y$, then $y$ is a linear combination of $A$'s column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

experiment with 
$$
A = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 100 \\
10 & 1000
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and calculate $Ax$ with, say,
$$
x = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
3  \\
7 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then  calculate $Ax$ with
$$
x = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
-13  \\
4 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following examples,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2  \end{bmatrix} = 1 \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix} + 2 \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ -1 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix} = 4 \begin{bmatrix} a \\ d \\ g \end{bmatrix} -1 \begin{bmatrix} b \\ e \\ h \end{bmatrix} + 11  \begin{bmatrix} c \\ f \\ i \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your statement holds by definition. Always $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Now if $x$ is a solution. Then it holds that $Ax = y$.